# Getting code for ASM for MIPS processors from C

Tags: c, assembly

I have the following code in C:

```
int main(){
printf("The factorial of 10 is %d\n", fact(10));
}

int fact(int n){

if(n < 1)
return 1;
else
return (n * fact(n-1));
}
```

and I need to write code for ASM for MIPS processors. But since I don't know ASM yet (I'm looking for good resources to learn), I was wondering whether it is possible to get it off some debugger maybe? Or is there any place which explains how to code in ASM for MIPS processors?

Comment: "See MIPS Run 2nd Edition " is great place to start.also you can use mips64-gnu-linux.gcc like cross compiler to dissemble the elf file..and more link for assembly programming this is a good one ..

http://chortle.ccsu.edu/AssemblyTutorial/index.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you you compile your code with gcc ( mips gcc), then you can generate your asm code from your C code.

Just use the `-S` option in the `gcc` command.

```
mips-linux-gcc -S test.c
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, but I use Windows.. how can I do it on Windows?

Comment: Get GCC for Windows? :)

Comment: @user3247785 For windows I do not have any idea. but you can look if you are using gcc as compilator for your mips architecture. if it's the case, then you can always us the -S option

Comment: I do have GCC, and I'm using Code::Blocks as my IDE. But I'm not exactly sure how to use this type of commands.

Comment: @user3247785 you can look in the Code::Blocks configuration. you can find some where the gcc command that the Code::Blocks use to build your code. use the cmmand in your DOS to build your C file with the -S option

Comment: @MOHAMED, When I use CMD, go to the specific folder where my main.c is, and I type gcc -whatever, it gives me an error that GCC is unrecognized command. What am I supposed to do in this case?

Comment: @user3247785 execute your gcc comand with the whole path `"C:\path\of\gcc-mips" -S main.c`; then you can find in the same folder of main.c a new file main.s that contains the assembly code

Comment: @user3247785 make sure that the gcc you use is for mips architecture in order to get assembly code for mips architecture

Comment: I think I added it inside the IDE, but the file it generates is empty, why is that?

Comment: @user3247785 I do not know what could be the reason without more details. especially that I m not familiar with gcc on windows

Comment: Ok, I finished it. Thanks a lot!